# Possible core-data bug: attributes named 'updated' don't work correctly?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data

I have a Core Data entity called `Post`. One of it's attributes is called `updated` and it is a date. The stored XML looks like this:

```
<attribute name="updated" type="date">266164481.00000000000000000000</attribute>
```

From this I concluded that the data is being stored correctly. When I read the data back the returned value is a `NSCFNumber`, not an `NSDate`.

However, when I changed the name from `updated` to `pubDate` it worked properly. `updated` isn't declared in the headers for `NSManagedObject` or `NSObject`, so I guess it must be a private method.

Has anyone else experienced this? Should I report it to Apple?

I figured this out after a few hours of head scratching/foul mouth anger.

Comment: Note that under Cocoa conventions, -updated is probably not a very good name for such a property. Consider -dateUpdated or -updatedDate instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`NSManagedObject` already has a property called [`isUpdated`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObject_Class/Reference/NSManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001171-BBCHECJE), which is set to `YES` when the object has changes that haven't been committed yet. This is a valid name for a getter for a `BOOL` value, so Core Data isn't doing anything with your `updated` property. You should rename your property.

Comment: see here for list of names you should avoid in core data : http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdManagedObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003397-235678

Comment: I didn't realize that Cocoa checked for methods with 'is' prefixes.

I though it just checked for methods named the same as the key and 'set' + key.

Comment: See the Key Value Coding Programming Guide for those details: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html

Answer (score 3):

If you renaming your property is not an option, you may set the value expression to `FUNCTION($source, "updated")` in the mapping model. This will force the migration to use the method named "updated" instead of the updated property (e.g. `[entity updated]` instead of `entity.updated`).

In general though, I'd agree with the accepted answer if possible use a name other than "updated".